Livewire wire:model not working with arrays, value is okay but the select is not auto selected or binded
    public bool $triggerModal = false;

    public $cols = [];

    public $selectedColumn = null;

    #[On('triggerModal')]
    public function triggerModal(int $importFileId)
    {
        $this->selectedColumn = 3;
        $this->cols = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
        $this->triggerModal = true;
    }

<div>
    <label class="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">Name</label>
         <select wire:model='selectedColumn'>
               <option value="">(Select Column)</option>
               @foreach ($cols as $col)
                      <option value="{{ $col }}">{{ $col }}</option>
                @endforeach
           </select>
</div>

Name Col: {{ $nameColumn }}

Very basic livewire component,
First the columns array is empty but then I'm just setting the cols and the data which is selected. The data is in the variable I can see. but the select is not bonded. The select is not selected to 3. But the variables have the perfect data.
Added wire:key all over the select foreach etc. and tried also.

Can you make the options selected by setting selected attribute?

Your code snippet works fine for me, and does what you'd expect it to do. Is there any wire:ignore somewhere that might cause the select to not update?

A possible solution is to dispatch an event from the backend passing the selectedColumn as parameter, then on the frontend side using Alpine to update the selected value at nextTick:
<select wire:model='selectedColumn'
        @modal-triggered.window="$nextTick(() => $wire.selectedColumn = $event.detail.selectedColumn)"
>
    <option value="">(Select Column)</option>

    @foreach ($cols as $col)
        <option value="{{ $col }}">{{ $col }}</option>
    @endforeach

</select>

class TestSelect extends Component
{
    public bool $triggerModal = false;
    public $cols = [];
    public $selectedColumn = null;


    #[On('triggerModal')]
    public function triggerModal(int $importFileId)
    {
        $selectedColumn = 3;

        $this->cols = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
        $this->triggerModal = true;

        $this->dispatch('modal-triggered', selectedColumn: $selectedColumn);
    }
}

